# Select latest row from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, max

I have this query with multiple tables and I got the following result. Then I want to group by t.id. I know I can simply use group by t.id but how can I select the latest row of t.id which is url tw5.jpg and created_time 10000004

```
SELECT p.url,t.name,t.num_photo,t.id
FROM photos AS p
LEFT JOIN tag_maps AS tm ON p.id = tm.photo_id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON t.id = tm.tag_id

url                       created_time    name      num_photo  id
assets/img/tags/tw1.jpg   1000001         my house  1           1
assets/img/tags/tw2.jpg   1000002         dog       1           2
assets/img/tags/tw3.jpg   1000003         taiwan    2           3
assets/img/tags/tw5.jpg   1000004         taiwan    2           3
```

This is what i get when using group by t.id

```
url                       created_time    name      num_photo  id
assets/img/tags/tw1.jpg   1000001         my house  1           1
assets/img/tags/tw2.jpg   1000002         dog       1           2
assets/img/tags/tw3.jpg   1000003         taiwan    2           3
```

And this is what i want

```
url                       created_time    name      num_photo  id
assets/img/tags/tw1.jpg   1000001         my house  1           1
assets/img/tags/tw2.jpg   1000002         dog       1           2
assets/img/tags/tw5.jpg   1000004         taiwan    2           3
```

EDITED

Photos table

```
id    url                      created_time
1     assets/img/tags/tw1.jpg  1000001
2     assets/img/tags/tw2.jpg  1000002
3     assets/img/tags/tw3.jpg  1000003
4     assets/img/tags/tw5.jpg  1000004
```

Tags table

```
id name     num_photo
1  my house 1
2  dog      1
3  taiwan   2
```

Tag_maps

```
id   tag_id   photo_id
1    1        1
2    2        2
3    3        3
4    3        4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit #2: Without seeing sample data from each table or the table structures, I am guessing that the following will work:

```
SELECT p.url,
  created_time,
  t.name,
  t.num_photo,
  t.id
FROM photos p
LEFT JOIN tag_maps AS tm 
    ON p.id = tm.photo_id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t 
    ON t.id = tm.tag_id
INNER JOIN
(
  select max(created_time) MaxDate, t.id
  FROM photos p
  LEFT JOIN tag_maps AS tm 
      ON p.id = tm.photo_id
  LEFT JOIN tags AS t 
      ON t.id = tm.tag_id
  group by t.id
) d
  on p.created_time = d.MaxDate
  and t.id = d.id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fd42/8)

Or another way to write this is with a subquery that returns the `max(photo_id)` by `tag_Id` from the `tag_maps` table and use that result in the join:

```
SELECT p.url,
  created_time,
  t.name,
  t.num_photo,
  t.id
FROM photos p
INNER JOIN
(
  select max(photo_id) photo_id, tag_id
  from tag_maps
  group by tag_id
) AS tm 
    ON p.id = tm.photo_id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t 
    ON t.id = tm.tag_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01c51/5)

Result is:

```
|                     URL | CREATED_TIME |     NAME | NUM_PHOTO | ID |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| assets/img/tags/tw1.jpg |      1000001 | my house |         1 |  1 |
| assets/img/tags/tw2.jpg |      1000002 |      dog |         1 |  2 |
| assets/img/tags/tw5.jpg |      1000004 |   taiwan |         2 |  3 |
```

<strike>Edit #1 since your url is different and you want the `max(id)`, then you should be able to use:</strike>

```
SELECT p.url,
  t.name,
  t.num_photo,
  Max(t.id) id
FROM photos p
LEFT JOIN tag_maps AS tm 
    ON p.id = tm.photo_id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t 
    ON t.id = tm.tag_id
group by t.name, t.num_photo
```

OP: You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT p.url,
    t.name,
    t.num_photo 
FROM
(
    select MAX(created_time) created_time, url, id
    from photos
    group by url, id
)  AS p
LEFT JOIN tag_maps AS tm 
    ON p.id = tm.photo_id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t 
    ON t.id = tm.tag_id
```

If the `id` value in the `photos` table is unique for each row, then you might need to use the following:

```
SELECT p1.url,
    t.name,
    t.num_photo 
FROM photos p1
inner join
(
    select MAX(created_time) created_time, url
    from photos
    group by url
)  AS p2
    on p1.url = p2.url
    and p1.created_time = p2.created_time
LEFT JOIN tag_maps AS tm 
    ON p1.id = tm.photo_id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t 
    ON t.id = tm.tag_id
```

Comment: Ok, the id in photos is unique so i use the second and works but why have to group by url in the subquery. And is there any way without using sub-query or other simply methods?

Comment: @vzhen if you don't use a `GROUP BY url` then you will only return one record with the `max(created_time)` you want to distinguish by each `url`.

Comment: hi, i just want to tell you, i got mistake just now and it was actually not working.  i edited my question, mind to take a look?
Thanks in adv

Comment: Doens't work, it seem max(t.id) doesn't select the newest created_time.
I edited my question again to be more clear.

Comment: It is hard to tell from the query, can you post the table structures and sample data from each table?

Comment: @vzhen I was guessing on the table structure so see my edit with a version that I think will work

Comment: Haha, BIG thanks for you. been trying for hours but didn't success and thanks for the sqlfiddle side. Will use it for sql question next time.