# Using max() to get the latest rows in a table, joined on another table

Tags: mysql, max, inner-join

I have the following schema which I am sadly not allowed to change:

```
+------------+ 
| vHistory v | 
+------------+       +---------------+
| id         |       | instance i    |         +----------------------+
| component  |       +---------------+         | environment e        |
| instance   |* === 1| id            |         +----------------------+
| version    |       | environment   |* ===== 1| idEnv                |
| date       |       +---------------+         | environment          |
+------------+                                 +----------------------+
```

(`vHistory` lists installation dates of componants on middleware; `instance` lists the an instance of a middleware server (eg "Tomcat 6.0.14 on machine "production-server-78"); `environment` means production/staging/etc)

I would like to produce a list for a particular `v.component` with the following columns:

```
v.id, v.version, e.environment, v.date
```

showing the latest installation of the chosen component *in each environment*. I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT  MAX(v.id), 
        e.environment, 
        v.version, 
        MAX(nv.date)
FROM vHistory v
  INNER JOIN instance i
    ON v.instance = i.id
  INNER JOIN environment e
    ON i.environment = e.idEnv
WHERE v.component = 100
GROUP BY e.environment
```

but I don't feel too confortable using the two `max()` functions like that...

Is there a better way? I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322539/select-latest-row-from-multiple-tables) question which joins on the date, but that scares me too because there could theoretically be another row with the same date.

Comment: You're correct to be uncomfortable about those two maxes, because they won't return values from the same row.

Comment: We like proper DDLs and/or sqlfiddles.

Comment: Sorry, I had never even heard of sqlfiddle until you mentioned it (I'm a Java programmer at heart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this will work:

```
SELECT  v.id, 
        e.environment, 
        v.date
FROM (  SELECT MAX(v2.id) AS id
        FROM vHistory v2
          INNER JOIN instance i2
            ON v2.instance = i2.id
          INNER JOIN environment e2
            ON i2.environment = e2.idEnv
        WHERE v2.component = 100
        GROUP BY e2.environment
      ) AS maxid
        JOIN vHistory v
        JOIN instance i
        JOIN environment e
          ON (  maxid.id = v.id
            AND v.instance = i.id
            AND i.environemnt = e.idEnv
           )
```

maxid will only contain the latest ids of the rows that match your query. Joining those ids to the whole table should return only the info you need.